# PHP / CodeIgniter functionality to get preferred countries to show first

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am trying to implement a Country - State interface, where if a particular country is chosen, the corresponding states show up on their own and can this be selected. I have been able to use JavaScripts with PHP/CodeIgniter function/code to implement this. But along with that, I also wish to show users a selection of con tries in which the site is currently viable.

Does anyone know of a library being used on CodeIgniter to implement such an interface, where I get 3-4 countries from my database on the top, without changing the DB or adding new tables/fields to our existing logic.

So as an example I need the following, in a drop down box:

```
United States
Australia
China
Canada
-------------
```

With only these countries showing first and not in the larger drop down below.

My current code does this from the DB which has all the Countries:

```
function addnationality() {
//alert('nationality');

var aFieldset = document.getElementById('nationality_div').getElementsByTagName('fieldset');
var count = aFieldset.length;
var cloned = aFieldset[0].cloneNode(true); // fieldset containing select, input & input
var parent = aFieldset[0].parentNode; // form
var aInput = parent.getElementsByTagName('select');
var cInput = cloned.getElementsByTagName('select');
cInput[0].name = 'country' + count;
cInput[0].value = '';
count++;
// insert clone
var oDiv = parent.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
parent.insertBefore(cloned, oDiv);

var emailcount = document.getElementById('nationality_count').value;

emailcount++;
document.getElementById('nationality_count').value = emailcount;
//alert(document.getElementById('phone_number_count').value);
}
```

Any ideas on how to modify the above or if anyone has a template on how to use this feature of displaying a few countries on the top.

```
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="company_country0" style="width : 150px" id="companycountryId"
                                onclick="companyCountryChange(this);"
                                onchange="companyCountryChange(this);">
                            <option value="" selected="">Select Country</option>
                            <?php foreach ($allCountries as $key => $value) { ?>
                                <option
                                    value="<?php echo $value->country_id; ?>" <?php if ($LinkedInUserInfo['country'] == $value->country_name) {
                                    echo "selected=\"selected\"";
                                } ?>><?php echo $value->country_name; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                        <select style="width : 150px" name="company_state0" id="Companystate0">
                            <option value="">Select State</option>
                            <?php foreach ($allState as $key => $value) { ?>
                                <option
                                    value="<?php echo $value->state_id; ?>" <?php if ($LinkedInUserInfo['state'] == $value->state_name) {
                                    echo "selected=\"selected\"";
                                } ?>><?php echo $value->state_name; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: I got the state-country combination style from another question, but that does not provide a solution for my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227159/ajax-drop-down-for-country-state-city-in-codeigniter?rq=1

Comment: Can you share the HTML and PHP you are using for this?

Comment: Just sort them when reading them from the database …

Comment: @CBroe how do I sort based on specific countries?

Comment: Do some _research_ … http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+sort+specific+records+on+top

Comment: what you would do is have a field in the database to mark which ones need to be placed at the top, set a value of 1 for the top or 0 for the bottom... then all you need to do is sort by that `order DESC, name ASC` (if you want them to appear at the top in A-Z).